# youtube api any parameter for part besides snippet not working

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, youtube, youtube-api

I am using the youtube api and am making an api request based on a search.

This all works. You can see it in [the playground here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&q=lfc&_h=5&).

in my code it looks like this:

```
fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=${query}&key=${API_KEY}`)
   .then(res => {
     return res.json();
    }).then(res => {
       setResults(res.items);
    });
});
```

I am passing it `snippet` as `part` in the url. This gives me some data, but I want to get more such as video duration etc. It looks like that can be retrieved by [more parameters to part](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#partial).

If I add `contentDetails` the api request fails. Does anyone know how to get more data besides the snippet?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, you have to make another call for retrieve such details *(like the `duration`, for example)* - but this time, you need the `videoId` and making the call to the [`videos.list` API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list).

So, using the first call you added in your question *(with a slighlty modifications)*, you get this URL:

*Request #1 - **Search**:*

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=5&q=lfc&fields=items(id%2FvideoId%2Csnippet%2Ftitle)%2CpageInfo&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

You can [test request #1 here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&maxResults=5&q=lfc&fields=items(id%252FvideoId%252Csnippet%252Ftitle)%252CpageInfo&_h=1&).

The results of the first request *(the "search" request)* are:

```
{
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1000000,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Liverpool FC"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "videoId": "a0IrBTg6zcI"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Bob Paisley: The Humble Genius | Liverpool's most successful manager in his own words"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "videoId": "sxMbgeBreJ0"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Inside Anfield: Liverpool 4-3 Crystal Palace | TUNNEL CAM from the Reds' dramatic win"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "videoId": "g4TknSKYG98"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "title": "1000 Premier League Goals at Anfield | Some of our favourite strikes"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "videoId": "pMYCN506lXk"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "title": "What Alex Oxlade-Chamberlain return REALLY means for Liverpool midfield? ● LFC News"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

---

Using the first item `videoId` `a0IrBTg6zcI`, create a request to the `videos.list` API as follows.

*Request #2 - **Video**:*

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2C+contentDetails&id=a0IrBTg6zcI&fields=items(contentDetails%2Fduration%2Csnippet%2Ftitle%2Cstatistics%2Cstatus(embeddable%2CpublishAt))%2CpageInfo&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

You can [test the request #2 here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.list?part=snippet%252C%20contentDetails&id=a0IrBTg6zcI&fields=items(contentDetails%252Fduration%252Csnippet%252Ftitle%252Cstatistics%252Cstatus(embeddable%252CpublishAt))%252CpageInfo&_h=3&).

The results of the second request *(the "video" request)* are:

```
{
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Bob Paisley: The Humble Genius | Liverpool's most successful manager in his own words"
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "duration": "PT1M47S"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

You can check the "duration" value in the "contentDetails" part.

You can try also the ([try-it](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%22snippet%2CcontentDetails%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22a0IrBTg6zcI%22%7D)) functionality available in the YouTube Data API (v3) reference documentation.

The linked try-it above has the parameters for get the information of the video with videoId `a0IrBTg6zcI` - the same used in this answer, but, this request has more data you might require.